# partial view error mvc requires a model item of type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I keep getting an error when trying to render a partial view:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is
>   of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Post_206B6491B2DC6BC95A9910F33BF20B9F1973E064A753CBEDF9E6C72F08A98532',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyBlogger.Post]'.

**PartialView:**

```
IEnumerable<MyBlogger.Post>


@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <p class="text-left">Similar Article: <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></p>

}
```

**MainDetails View:**

```
@model MyBlogger.Post

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MainDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</h2>

<header class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="post-heading">
                    @*<a href="#">*@
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/img/post-bg.jpg" alt="">

                        <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ShortDescription)</h1>
                    <p class="text-left">Posted by <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BlogUserEmail)</a> on @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostedOn)</p>
                    <p class="text-left">Category <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category.Name)</a></p>

                    @*</a>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<fieldset>
    <div class="display-field">
        @*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BlogUserEmail)*@
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Description))
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Modified)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@Html.Partial("SimilarPosts") // here
```

**MainDetails Action:**

```
    public ActionResult MainDetails(string urlslug)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.First(m => m.UrlSlug == urlslug);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(post);
    }
```

Comment: Foreach item in my IEnumerable<Post> display the Title of each post?

Comment: Your return a single `Post` to the view, then you call a partial which expects a collection of `Post`. Does typeof `Post` itself contain an property which is `IEnumerable<Post>`?

Comment: You are not sending any data to your partial. You are using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402898(v=vs.118).aspx) overload, when you should be using [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926(v=vs.118).aspx). You should get the list/enumerable for the "similar posts" and setting it as the model for the partial. You could, for example, get the list of similar posts in the `MainDetails` action, save it in `ViewBag` and pass it to the partial.

Comment: How I have tried ViewBag.posts = db.Posts.ToList(); and @Html.Partial("SimilarPosts", ViewData.ToList()) Still cant return anything to the partial.

Comment: I don't know how you define your "similar posts". Let's assume that you will render all the posts (just like you wrote in your comment). In the `MainDetails` action write: `ViewBag.posts = db.Posts.ToList();`. Then, inside your `MainDetails.cshtml` replace this line `@Html.Partial("SimilarPosts") // here` with this one `@Html.Partial("SimilarPosts", ViewBag.posts) // here`. Please note that I'm passing the posts stored in `ViewBag` as the model of the `Partial` method.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyBlogger.Post>' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it's your model structure that's causing you the issues. You send an individual `Post` object to your main view, yet your child view expects an `IEnumerable<Post>`. The best solution here is to create a view model that encompasses both:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public Post CurrentPost { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyBlogger.Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate it with something like:

```
public ActionResult MainDetails(string urlslug)
{
    Post post = db.Posts.First(m => m.UrlSlug == urlslug);
    List<Post> posts = db.Posts.ToList();

    PostViewModel model = new PostViewModel
    {
         CurrentPost = post,
         Posts = posts
    };

    if (post == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Then your main view would be:

```
@model PostViewModel

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.Title)</h2>

<header class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="post-heading">
                    @*<a href="#">*@
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/img/post-bg.jpg" alt="">

                        <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.ShortDescription)</h1>
                    <p class="text-left">Posted by <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.BlogUserEmail)</a> on @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.PostedOn)</p>
                    <p class="text-left">Category <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.Category.Name)</a></p>

                    @*</a>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<fieldset>
    <div class="display-field">
        @*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.BlogUserEmail)*@
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.CurrentPost.Description))
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.Modified)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@Html.Partial("SimilarPosts", Model.Posts)
```

Then your partial would be the same:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlogger.Post>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p class="text-left">Similar Article: <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to create a viewmodel to hold all the data for the view. 
The viewmodel is a class that represents the data you want to display in the view. If you have worked with Sql Server you can think of it as a sql view, that in context, it collects things into a group that can then be used on the page.

In your case you have 2 specific operations you want to achieve with your view.

- The model of the blog being called **(0)**
- Similar blogs associated with that blog **(1)**

**ViewModel**

```
public class BlogDetailsViewModel{
    public Blog SingleBlogItem { get; set; } // (0)
    public IEnnumerable<Blog> SimilarBlogs { get; set; } // (1)
}
```

In that code we have setup the viewmodel to hold what we need for the view. It is the model for that view. Right now it is just set as representations for the objects of `Blog (0)` and `IEnumerable<Blog> (1)` . How are similar blogs related to single blog item though? This is for you to decide. I will just add a simple solution for the purposes of this post.

**BlogPostRelation ( POCO Class )**

```
 public class BlogPostRelation{
       public int Id {get; set;}
       public int BlogId {get; set;}
       public int SimilarBlogId {get; set;}
 }
```

So in this class each row in the table will be connected by the blog item and an associated blog item which is similar. When you save a blog item that has similar blogs you then then also add to this table with a main BlogId **(0)** and SimilarBlogId **(1)** . So if you save 4 similar blogs there will be 4 rows in this table with that saved blogs `BlogId`.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult BlogDetails(int blogId){

     // First find the blog you want. We assign it here instead of in the  
     // new BlogDetailViewModel so that we can use it as a condition on 
     // the similiar blogs
     Blog blog = context.Blog.firstOrDefault(b => b.BlogId == blogId);

     BlogDetailViewModel model = new BlogDetailViewModel{
            SingleBlogItem = blog,
            SimilarBlogs = context.BlogPostRelation.Where(b => b.BlogId == blog.BlogId).ToList()
     }

     // Now pass this viewmodel to the main view
     return View(model)
}
```

You now have a model ( *you probably want to add conditions if not found* ) that you can use in the view and the partial view, remembering that the spec for the view was to have a `Blog (0)` and a `IEnumerable<Blog> (1)` . Which are now contained in the viewmodel as `SingleBlogItem (0)` and `SimilarBlogs (1)`

**View**

```
@model PATH.TO.VIEWMODEL.BlogDetailViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SingleBlogItem.Modified)
```

So here in the main view you can assign the model as you normally would by just adding a prefix of `SingleBlogItem (0)` to the model ( it is strongly typed so there will be intellesense ) . And then for the partialview

**Call to partialview**

```
@Html.Partial("SimilarPosts",Model.SimilarBlogs)
```

Here you are passing the similar posts which live in the viewmodel as `Model.SimilarBlogs (1)` to the partialview

**PartialView**

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <p class="text-left">Similar Article: 
        <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a></p>
 }
```

Lastly you call the Blog object as an IEnumerable, for the model of that partialview without a error, because this partialview wants a `IEnumerable<Blog>` and is getting that from the main view when it passes that model `Model.SimilarBlogs (1)` into the partialview

It is good to remember that when the view is displayed all the things that the view needs to display are packaged in the model , which is work that should be done in the controller.

*I know i have created this as a blog and not based on your actual models in your question. I just did not want to get mixed up between what you had created and a simple description to the solution. I thought it would be easier to describe as a simple blog post relative to similar blogs , which seems closely related to the question asked*